# Why does this function give me correct values up to a certain range of inputs only?

Tags: c++, function, if-statement, recursion, break

This is a function I made to calculate the factorial of a number

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int fact(int n) {
    if (n < 0) {
        cout << "Negative values not allowed";
        exit(4);
    }
    if (n == 0 || n == 1)
        return 1;
    else
        return n * fact(n - 1);
}
```

Now for some reason this code gives me correct answers up to x=12 (I used wolfram to check) after that it gives me wrong answers which is very strange why is that ?

Comment: `std::cout << std::numeric_limits<int>::max() << '\n';` will show you the maximum value an `int` can hold.

Comment: `unsigned long long fact(int n)`{ ... }` will allow you to compute higher value of the factorial.

Comment: Your result is too big for a 32bit integer and [overflows](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_arithmetic)

Comment: @TedLyngmo so after the numeric limit does it just give random answers ? because it gives me inaccurate numbers then at bigger values of x it gives me 0

Comment: After you've passed the limit your program has undefined behavior because of signed integer overflow. With undefined behavior your program could do just about anything.

Comment: The behaviour of `int` overflow is undefined. What probably happens is the result is computed mod 2**32. By then your factorial is a multiple of a large power of 2, which explains the attaining of 0.

Comment: @FadedYoussef -- [Use a big integer type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67630357/c-factorial-of-number-100/67630658#67630658).