# Integer overflow in unsigned long long array

Tags: c++

I was trying to make cached Fibonacci sequence, but seem to be running into integer overflow (even if the data type is unsigned long long) after nth position = 247, the compiler outputs strange erroneous negative results, which I was not hoping for. Was wondering what a solution to this is, beyond n=247, and how I can increase accurate result up to essentially n= any positive integer if that possible... Thanks.

I was also trying to set the array capacity to the nthPos but it only accepts constant integers (not even constant variables!), was wondering what a way around this is...

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>
#include <time.h>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;


int FibonacciRecursiveFunc(int nthPos) {
    unsigned long long firstNum = 0; unsigned long long secondNum = 1;
    unsigned long long PastFibonacciCache[300] = { firstNum,secondNum };

    if (find(PastFibonacciCache, end(PastFibonacciCache), nthPos-1) != end(PastFibonacciCache)) {
        return nthPos - 1;
    }
    else {
        for (int i = 2; i < nthPos; i++) {
            PastFibonacciCache[i] = PastFibonacciCache[i - 1] + PastFibonacciCache[i - 2];
            if (i > 300) {
                unsigned long long SecondLastTerm = PastFibonacciCache[299];
                unsigned long long lastTerm = PastFibonacciCache[300];
                PastFibonacciCache[300] = {}; PastFibonacciCache[0] = SecondLastTerm; PastFibonacciCache[1] = lastTerm;
                i - 300;  nthPos - 300;
            }
        }
        return PastFibonacciCache[nthPos%300-1];
    }
}

int main() {
    string inputVAL; int nthPos;
    cout << "Greetings, enter a valid n value | n >= 1\n" << "type exit, quit or break to quit program \n\n" << endl << " ->";
    getline(cin, inputVAL);
    string exit_Methods[3] = { "exit", "quit", "break" };
    while (find(exit_Methods, end(exit_Methods), inputVAL) == end(exit_Methods)) {
        bool exception_caught = true;

        try {
            nthPos = stoi(inputVAL);

            exception_caught = false;
        }
        catch (invalid_argument) {
            cerr << "invalid argument" << endl;
        }
        catch (out_of_range) {
            cerr << "number is too big" << endl;
        }
        catch (exception) {
            cerr << "something went horribly wrong :v" << endl;
        }
        if (!exception_caught) {

            //begintimer for calculation speed
            time_t begin, end;
            time(&begin);
            if (nthPos >= 1) {
                cout << FibonacciRecursiveFunc(nthPos) << endl;
            }
            else {
                cout << "ERR" << endl;
            }


            // measure elapsed time
            time(&end);
            time_t elapsed = end - begin;

            printf("Time measured: %ld seconds.\n\n", elapsed);
        }
        cout << "enter a valid n value | n >= 0 ->";
        getline(cin, inputVAL);
    }
}
```

Comment: you cannot compute the factorial of any integer, because the factorial of the largest integer is larger than the largest integer. No matter what type you choose there is a limit somewhere

Comment: What's the value for 245 and 246 (or 247 if that's still valid)?  How does that compare with 2^64 - 1?  If `unsigned long long` is no longer big enough to hold the values, you will need to use (and possibly implement) some sort of multi-precision (integer) arithmetic.  There are libraries available to do that — for example, GMP from https://gmplib.org/ (see also MPC from https://www.multiprecision.org/mpc/ and MPFR from https://www.mpfr.org/ — all of these are used by GCC).

Comment: Look into GPM : https://gmplib.org/

Comment: `unsigned long long PastFibonacciCache[300]` => 300 is the SIZE of this array.  It is not a valid INDEX, the highest legal index is 299.  But you access 300 in several places.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number: Fibonacci sequence doesn't grow anywhere near as fast as factorial, however the same argument applies.

Comment: actually the limit is 47... which is kind of a bummer because I hoping for even more :/

Comment: @LuvRathod [See this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67630357/c-factorial-of-number-100/67630658#67630658).  It uses factorial, but you get the idea.  Also, using Binet's formula, you can get the nth Fibonacci formula using a closed formula without iterating.  But you would have to store the values in a floating point variables, not integers.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> int FibonacciRecursiveFunc(int nthPos) {
> ```

The return type of your function is `int`. The maximum value representable by `int` varies between systems, but let's assume that it is 2147483647 on your system.

The 247th fibonacci number is 1152058411884454788302593034206568772452674037325128. This number is greater than 2147483647. You cannot represent so large number with an `int`.

> was wondering what a way around this is

You cannot use fundamental types. You can use arbitrary precision arithmetic.