# Finding number of postorder BSTs permutations

Tags: c++, algorithm, binary-search-tree, permutation

I'm dealing with a problem which says:
find permutations from 1 to n of BSTs (***postorder*** traversal).
for example for n = 3: we have 6! - 1 = 5 permutations because (3 1 2) is not a BST postorder.

I Wrote an algorithm for this, for example for n = 4:

[image]

In total we have 3!+2!+2!+3! = 16

I've written this piece of code using this algorithm to calculate number of permutations from 1 to n:

```
int calcPerm(int n)
{
    int sum = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        sum += (fact(n-1-i) * fact(i));
    }
    return sum;
}
```

I know for some n, 1 <= n <= 20 it gives me a wrong answer and I don't know why its not working.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Pro tip: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems?r=Saves_AllUserSaves

Comment: *and I don't know why its not working* -- An `int` is usually 32-bits.  `20!` cannot fit in a 32-bit integer.

Comment: [See this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67630357/c-factorial-of-number-100).

Comment: thanks, but does this algorithm even work? or is it because of big factorials?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Factorials grow quickly out of range of a 32-bit integer. But taking a step back, that formula (algorithm) is not correct. You write:

> Wrote an algorithm for this, for example for n = 4: [...] In total we have 3!+2!+2!+3! = 16

But 16 is not the correct outcome for  = 4. It should be 14.

Here is a table of all possible postorders, and whether they can be a BST or not:

| postorder | valid BST? |
| --- | --- |
| 1 2 3 4 | yes |
| 1 2 4 3 | yes |
| 1 3 2 4 | yes |
| 1 3 4 2 | no |
| 1 4 2 3 | no |
| 1 4 3 2 | no |
| 2 1 3 4 | yes |
| 2 1 4 3 | yes |
| 2 3 1 4 | yes |
| 2 3 4 1 | yes |
| 2 4 1 3 | no |
| 2 4 3 1 | yes |
| 3 1 2 4 | no |
| 3 1 4 2 | yes |
| 3 2 1 4 | yes |
| 3 2 4 1 | yes |
| 3 4 1 2 | no |
| 3 4 2 1 | yes |
| 4 1 2 3 | no |
| 4 1 3 2 | yes |
| 4 2 1 3 | no |
| 4 2 3 1 | no |
| 4 3 1 2 | no |
| 4 3 2 1 | yes |

So although your algorithm gives correct results for  < 4, it starts overshooting the expected outcome from 4 onwards.

### Catalan numbers

The number of postorders that can describe a BST really corresponds to the number of *shapes* a binary tree with  nodes can have.  Once the *shape* of the tree is established, there is only one way to label the nodes with the given numbers so that it would be a BST. And so this also uniquely corresponds to a postorder.

The number of shapes of a binary tree is given by [Catalan numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_number#Applications_in_combinatorics).

We can use an incremental formula to calculate the first 21 of them, and for  = 20, the result is 6,564,120,420. An `int` does not have enough range for this, so you should use `long` instead.

Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

std::vector<long> getCatalans(const int n) {
    std::vector<long> results = {1};
    long c = 1;
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; ++i) {
        c = 2*(2*i - 1) * c / (i + 1);
        results.push_back(c);
    }
    return results;
}

int main() {
    std::vector<long> catalans = getCatalans(20);
    for (int n = 1; n <= 20; n++) {
        std::cout << n << ". " << catalans[n] << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Output:

```
1. 1
2. 2
3. 5
4. 14
5. 42
6. 132
7. 429
8. 1430
9. 4862
10. 16796
11. 58786
12. 208012
13. 742900
14. 2674440
15. 9694845
16. 35357670
17. 129644790
18. 477638700
19. 1767263190
20. 6564120420
```

Answer (score 1):

FYI, the number of BSTs with nodes numbered 1 to n (inclusive) is given by the nth Catalan number:

[image: catalan bst stanford]

Source: https://web.stanford.edu/class/archive/cs/cs106b/cs106b.1214/sections/section8/

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

unsigned long long CatalanRecursive(unsigned int n) {
  if (n <= 1) return 1;
  unsigned long long res = 0;
  for (unsigned int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    res += CatalanRecursive(i) * CatalanRecursive(n - i - 1);
  }
  return res;
}

unsigned long long CatalanDynamicProgramming(unsigned int n) {
  std::vector<unsigned long long> catalan(n + 1, 0);
  catalan[0] = catalan[1] = 1;
  for (unsigned int i = 2; i <= n; i++) {
    for (unsigned int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
      catalan[i] += catalan[j] * catalan[i - j - 1];
    }
  }
  return catalan[n];
}

int main() {
  unsigned int n = 3;
  std::cout << "CatalanRecursive(" << n << ") = " << CatalanRecursive(n) << '\n';
  std::cout << "CatalanDynamicProgramming(" << n << ") = " << CatalanDynamicProgramming(n) << '\n';
  n = 4;
  std::cout << "CatalanRecursive(" << n << ") = " << CatalanRecursive(n) << '\n';
  std::cout << "CatalanDynamicProgramming(" << n << ") = " << CatalanDynamicProgramming(n) << '\n';
  n = 5;
  std::cout << "CatalanRecursive(" << n << ") = " << CatalanRecursive(n) << '\n';
  std::cout << "CatalanDynamicProgramming(" << n << ") = " << CatalanDynamicProgramming(n) << '\n';
  return 0;
}
```

**Output:**

```
CatalanRecursive(3) = 5
CatalanDynamicProgramming(3) = 5
CatalanRecursive(4) = 14
CatalanDynamicProgramming(4) = 14
CatalanRecursive(5) = 42
CatalanDynamicProgramming(5) = 42
```